# Azure DevOps updating multiple build defintions

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am currently using the Azure DevOps API to update multiple build definitions based on a template. Is there another recommended way to update multiple build definitions without having to edit each one of them manually e.g. adding a build step or overwriting an existing build step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

- Task groups
- YAML builds, with one YAML file used by multiple definitions.

Comment: We share build definition ans step using YAML files stored on its own git repository.